# Instagram Subscription for Edited posts

Tags: instagram

I created an Instagram subscription https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/
My callback is hit every time a user creates a NEW post. Is there a way to know if a post has been EDITED? It doesn't look like this functionality is supported on the Instagram developer site and I cannot find a solid answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to be notified when a post has been edited.  You'd have to store the post when you're first notified, and then poll it to check for changes (not recommended).

Comment: Yeah, I've come to the same conclusion. Wish there was a better way to keep updated Instagram posts.